# Couch db date and overFlow

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

I need to compute an easy task using CouchDB. But I have encountered some problems : 
I cannot convert properly timestamps in the Sate string representation. 
this is my my function:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.temp > -50 && doc.temp < 50 ) {
        var date = new Date(doc.time); 
        emit(date, doc.temp);
    }
}
```

I need to group different events happening in the same hour. But this class produces a null date object and I don't understand why.

Furthermore, my reduce function which computes the average  does not work either because it goes in overflow.

```
function(keys, values) {
  return sum(values)/values.length;
}
```

I can manage to make the first function working if I change to this form :

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.temp > -50 && doc.temp < 50 ) {
        emit(Math.round(doc.time/360000), doc.temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: See this solution: http://tobyho.com/2009/10/07/taking-an-average-in-couchdb/

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your reduce function does not work is because it does not handle the re-reduce case.

In your reduce function, you process *parts* of results of the map function in your reduce function. When this is the case the rereduce parameter is false.

Your reduce function also needs to process *parts* of the results of the previous reduce calls. When this is the case the rereduce parameter is true.

See the documentation: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Reduce_vs_rereduce

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB provides very efficient built-in reduce functions. When you need to compute an average, it is usually a good idea to use [`_stats`](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions#A_stats) as the reduce function and then compute `sum/count` client-side.